# Windows Explorer - keyboard shortcut to duplicate files/folders

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there a keyboard shortcut to duplicate files/folders in Windows Explorer?
CTRL-C and CTRL-V would work, but is there a single key for this?

Thanks!
Florian

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

But you can drag and drop while maintaining Ctrl to create a copy too.

Comment: Awesome! Opposed to CTRL-C and CTRL-V  this does not clear your clipboard!

Answer (score -5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> creates a duplicate in a new window

Comment: The OP is asking about creating a copy of a file or folder, not opening a new explorer window with the same view.